# WinDbg: is there any relationship between it and "Windows Symbol Packages"

Tags: asp.net, windows

Our live servers (ASP.NET) intermittently run into a mysterious error, but i cannot access the servers direcly.

After researching, I refer to http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx and find **Windows Symbol Packages** in that page.

What is that? And how is it connected to WinDbg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh?

Symbol packages are offline packages you can get instead of connecting to the symbol server directly and downloading symbols on demand.

WinDBG is a debugger. It can use symbols to help you understand stack traces, etc. Without symbols you only get raw addresses.